# Samsung Galaxy S3 not detected on my PC after installing a custom ROM

Tags: samsung, custom-roms, usb-connection-mode

While installing a custom ROM on Samsung Galaxy S3 (SGH T999), I think I deleted some key files, so now my PC is not able to detect my Android phone, nor do I have any saved ROMs on the phone to recover. I do not have an SD card slot but have Clockworks Recovery software.

How can I make my PC detect the Android phone?

Comment: Did you reinstall your drivers? Did you reinstall ADB and Fastboot? Do you have the ROMs on your PC? Get everything setup again and redo. You don't mention what device you have, nor Android version. Plus what steps you have initially performed that have led to your conundrum

Comment: Hi I managed to fix the phone. I have mentioned my steps in the answer below.I have Galaxy S3,SGH T999.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an option in CWM to enable MTP to gain access to storage over USB.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the phone. I flashed it with a custom ROM for T-Mobile using Odin.

Initially, the phone was not getting detected, so I tried using ADB to transfer a ROM. That worked, but IMEI no. was still not available. It showed null, so I flashed it with stock ROM.

Anyone who has the same issue can try my method. Here is the link to flash Stock ROM using Odin: http://androidxda.com/flash-samsung-stock-rom-using-odin